# Linear algebra prove sin(x) and sin(2x) are linear dependent iff cos(x) is in Q

Tags: linear-algebra

this is a question that was assigned to us in our homework for Linear Algebra.

So far, my only idea is using the trig identity. asin(x)+2bsin(x)cos(x) = 0. From there, if I factor out the sin(x), that results in sin(x)(a+2bcos(x)) = 0. If I set both =0, I get x=0+(pi)n or I end up with (a+2bcos(x)). I'm not sure if I understand the problem correctly because shouldn't for all a and b asin(x) + bsin(2x) = 0 if x is a 0 or a multiple of pi?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you try to tackle the problem? Have you tried to see what happens for various $x$ values?

Comment: Hint: $\sin{2x}=2\sin{x}\cos{x}$.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. If a product $\alpha\beta$ is zero, then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ do not need to be **both** zero, but instead **at least one of them** needs to be zero.

In symbols: If $\alpha\beta=0$, then $\alpha=0$ **or** $\beta=0$.

What if $\alpha=\sin(x)$ and $\beta=a+2b\cos(x)$?

Comment: So if sin(x) = 0 then you get 0 +- (pi)n and if a+2bcos(x) = 0 then cos(x) = -a/2b. I'm assuming that is the answer because then cos(x) must be a part of the rational set. However, I'm still confused about the other side, that is sin(x) = 0 because cos(x) would not necessarily have to be a part of the rational set for that to be true right?

Comment: @MathHelp Well, if $\sin(x)=0$ then you can obtain the value of $\cos(x)$ quite explicitly.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help.